# Why does my GridSearchCV().fit() run slower now that I'm using a better processor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm running a range of GridSearchCV().fits for a RandomForestClassifier over a range of parameter sets.

From the start I have been setting n_jobs=-1 on the RandomForestClassifier.

For the past week I've been doing this with an i5 4-core processor and it was okay but not very fast. I've just upgraded to a computer with an AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2970WX with 24 cores and 48 logical processors. However it doesn't seem to be running any faster at all! When running the GridSearchCV, the majority of cores are either idle or at very low utilization.

What's going wrong?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/34416/scikit-learn-n-jobs-parameter-on-cpu-usage-memory

Comment: @PV8 So does it mean that there isn't enough memory in his system to make 48 copies of the data, and thus not all cores can be utilized?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the size of your parameter grid is smaller than 48?